# Monitor problem during booting

Tags: boot, monitor

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on a HP EliteDesk 800 G2. Recently the m/c was packed up and stored for a few days. Since reconnecting everything, the monitor turns off after 2 seconds of Ubuntu logo screen. If I turn the monitor off using its Power switch and then on again, I can see the login screen, but it turns off after two seconds — and so on, multiple times!, through the boot sequence until the left Shift key is pressed during entry of a URL in Chrome. Occasionally left Shift keeps the monitor on earlier, but it seems to be a random effect.
This is incredibly frustrating and is new behaviour since being packed up and stored for a few days.
Would massively appreciate any suggestions for returning to 'normal' boot operation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears it may be an inverter failure in the monitor. Turned down the brightness and I can boot normally again without having to turn the monitor off and on to see the content displayed. Time to shop for a new monitor!